# Showing All Results For Search Option Selected From Combobox

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql database with columns id, division, district, branch, scm_name and scm_address. Here condition is Like - One branch name for many scm_names...and there are total 207 branches with about 1000 scm_names

I have used following code to search by branch through combo-box options and after clicking serach button, user get redirected to results.php page. here i want to show all scm_names with that selected branch name.

Currently it is showing only one first row as result. How to show all scm_names for that branch ?

code used -

**index.php**

```
    $query="SELECT * FROM tablename  group by branch   order by branch ASC ";

    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ('error submitting');
    $count=1;
     echo "<select name='district'>";
      while($drop=mysql_fetch_array($result)){


      echo "<option value=$drop[id]>$count) $drop[branch] Branch From - $drop[district] District</option>";

     $count++;}

     echo "</select>";
```

With this code it is populating a list of 207 branches from all 1000 rows in database correctly.

**results.php**

```
 $district = $_POST['district'];

 $sql = "SELECT  division, district, branch, GROUP_CONCAT(scm_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS scm_name FROM tablename where id = '$district' GROUP BY branch";


$results1=mysql_query($sql);


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $results1 )) {?>

Division :     $row["division"]
Division :     $row["district"]
Division :     $row["branch"]
Division :     $row["scm_name"]
Division :     $row["scm_address"]

 <?}?>
```

But it is showing only one - first row as results. so oly one scm_name is diplayed as result.

How to show All scm_names with same branch name value in database ?

Comment: You can't use PHP variables after `?>`. How are you seeing the results?

Comment: SHouldn't it be `WHERE district = '$district'`, not `WHERE id = '$district'`?

Comment: You should also use avoid breaking braces like you have in your results loop. Instead use colon like: `<?php while(): ?> HTML/PHP <?php endwhile; ?>` This works with most control flow statements.

Comment: @Barmar Sir id='$district' is from index.php where user selects branch name...

Comment: All rows with the same `branch` also have the same `id`?

Comment: @Barmar No sir...each row is with unique id

Comment: @prodigitalson I tried removing braces and using colon. But result is same...it is showing only one result and not all scm_names for same branch

Comment: Why are you putting `$drop[id]` into `index.php` instead of `$drop[branch]`?

Comment: the problem is that you're just selecting one row with `WHERE id='$district'`, since it's a unique ID.

Comment: You need to put something that identifies all the rows of the branch into `index.php`, and then use that same column in `results.php`.

Comment: @Barmar Ohhh great...i changed drop{id} to drop{branch} in index.php and in results.php changed id=$district to branch=$district and it worked... can u put ur suggestion as answer so i can mark it as correct answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `id` column will just select a single row. You need to use a column that matches all rows in the branch.

In `index.php`, use:

```
echo "<option value='$drop[branch]'>$count) $drop[branch] Branch From - $drop[district] District</option>";
```

And in `results.php`, test that column:

```
$sql = "SELECT  division, district, branch, GROUP_CONCAT(scm_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS scm_name
        FROM tablename 
        where branch = '$district'";
```

Since you're just returning the row for a single `branch`, there's no need for `GROUP BY branch` here. You also don't need a `while` loop to display the results, since this will just return one row.

Comment: one more query, how to show address of each scm_name next to his name ? as it is showing all scm_name but only few first addresses and not all addresses

Comment: Instead of using `GROUP_CONCAT` to return everything as one row, just return the rows normally. Then you can loop through all the rows, showing the `scm_name` and `scm_address`.